# flashing vbios on my MSI machine

Tags: flashing, freedos

Just tried to flash my vbios on my gs70 pro using freedos, but the bios bat file on the usb stick that I need to execute is not listed when I do a "dir". I only see the freedos system files.

I guess this is because I'm looking inside the OS compressed file.

I am using this guide: http://tw.msi.com/files/pdf/VBIOS_Update_under_DOS_mode_EN.pdf

I probably missed something simple but can't seem to figure it out. Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. had to switch to C: //*by typing: C: {ENTER} *//